# Why ethereum nodes needs to sync in private net?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I getting geth up and running with: `geth --datadir data --rpc`. and Mist up and running with: `/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc http://localhost:8545`. So mist is running in private net, so there won't be any blocks to download right? then why mist is still showing `ethereum nodes needs to sync, looking for peers` and it takes forever to finish.

Comment: Do you find why ?

Comment: Yes. pls see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Because a private net is actually the same as a testnet, you still need to sync the blocks.